# A variant of Brouwer's fixed point theorem.

Tags: algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems

In the course on algebraic topology I came across a result called **Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem** which states that any map (continuous function) $f : D^n \longrightarrow D^n$ has a fixed point for $n \geq 2.$ The proof uses **No Retraction Theorem** which states that there doesn't exist any retraction from $D^n$ onto $S^{n-1},$ for $n \geq 2.$ Now I have a question here.

**Question** $:$ Can we impose some further condition on $f$ so that it has a fixed point on $\partial D^n\ $?

Our instructor suggested that we may take a map which takes the upper hemisphere to the upper hemisphere then such maps will have a fixed point on the boundary. But I don't get his point. Could anyone suggest me some idea on it?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Yes, require that $f$ map $D$ to a single point on $S$.

Comment: @O.Peters I don't get your point. Could you please explain a bit more about it?

Comment: The Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem is also true for $n = 1$.

Comment: @Paul Frost I agree with you but I think it is no longer a consequence of **No Retraction Theorem.** It can be proved independently in the context of real analysis.

Comment: Yes, there is an elementary proof using the IVT. Anyway, it is also a consequence of the No Retraction Theorem which is valid in all dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your instructor means is this:

The upper hemisphere of $S^{n-1} = \partial D^n$ is the space
$$S^{n-1}_+ = \{(x_1,\ldots, x_n) \in S^{n-1} \mid x_n \ge 0 \} .$$
The map $h : S^{n-1}_+ \to D^{n-1}, h((x_1,\ldots, x_n)) = (x_1,\ldots, x_{n-1})$, is clearly a homeomorphism.

If $f(S^{n-1}_+) \subset S^{n-1}_+$, then consider the map
$$g : D^{n-1} \stackrel{h^{-1}}{\longrightarrow} S^{n-1}_+ \stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} S^{n-1}_+ \stackrel{h}{\longrightarrow} D^{n-1} .$$
Using the Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem, $g$ has a fixed point $y$. Thus $x = h^{-1}(y) \in S^{n-1}_+$ is a fixed point of $f$.

Comment: Here you are assuming that $n \geq 2.$ Right? Otherwise you cannot use Brouwer's fixed point theorem for $g.$ Brouwer's fixed point theorem is not even valid for $n = 0.$ Because for $n = 0$ we can simply take the map which switches $-1$ and $1.$ Then it will have no fixed point.

Comment: It also works for $n =1$. In that case $n-1 =0$ and $D^0$ is a one-point space. This is a trivial case.

Comment: Oh sorry. I messed up $D^0$ with $S^0.$